# xcodebuild test command for using with jenkins doesn´t work

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcode4.5

I am having one problem that is killing me. Here it is: I have and app project in xCode that goes perfect when I tried to do everything in xCode UI. Which that I mean build, run, test or whatever in all the different targets that I have (3), 2 of the App and one for the tests.

THe problem comes when I tried to install a continous integration to my system in Jenkins. I need to execute some commands in shell for it. Command like this one:

```
xcodebuild -project MYPROJECT -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme TESTS_SCHEME TEST_AFTER_BUILD=YES
```

I also have tried with this other one that in the end it does the same:

```
xcodebuild -project MY_PROJECT -target TEST_TARGET -sdk iphonesimulator  -configuration "Debug"
```

Then is when the problems cames out, the terminal says the following:

```
....PrecompiledHeaders/MYLIBRARY-Prefix-hhjuztynfruquodlgqxroyfibfkh/MYLIBRARY-Prefix.pch.d
clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=4.3'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /Users/nicoyuste/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-bxpgsdbefuawmiexyikbtvsatlsf/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MYLIBRARY-Prefix-hhjuztynfruquodlgqxroyfibfkh/MYLIBRARY-Prefix.pch.pth MYLIBRARY-Prefix.pch normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I´ve been looking in the Internet (almost in here) but everything what I found with same problem didn´t work for me. The xCode version is 4.5 and if you do `xcodebuild -version` is what I get so that´s fine.

I also have tried changing headers files and everything what I have found around but nothing fixes my problem...

any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing people who is still wondering about this. I posted this question a long time ago. I stopped using xcodebuild and I am using [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) now, it works much better. This tool is developed by Facebook.

Comment: thank god for that link! I had so much issues with xcodebuild in combination with the bamboo xcode plugin. this is way better, although I need to write my own build script.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a custom build script, you can pass -arch i386 to xcodebuild

For instance:

```
xcodebuild -project MY_PROJECT -target TEST_TARGET -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration "Debug" -arch i386
```

(Scroll all the way to the right in the code sample above. The relevant flag is `-arch i386`)

Should force it to build against i386. However, you need to make sure i386 is in your VALID_ARCHS settings for the target.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone running into the same annoying problem again, I will share my script here:
Remember to run this command under the directory that has the xcodeproj file.

```
xcodebuild \
-project "full-path-to-your-xcodeproj-file" \
-target YOUR_TARGET \
-sdk iphonesimulator6.1 \
-arch i386 \
-configuration Debug \
VALID_ARCHS="armv6 armv7 i386" \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1" \
clean install
```

I modified the TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY because I only build for iPhone. If you want to build for both iPhone and iPad, delete this line or replace with TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY="1, 2".

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem reside in that your are building for the simulator specifying arm as the architecture, try changing it to i386

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem after upgrading to Xcode 4.5 on my build machine.    In my case, I have a third-party library that can't be built for armv7s (yet) and so, I set the `Architectures` build setting to `armv7`.   Worked fine for unit tests, simulator builds, and the like inside of Xcode.    However, when I did the command-line build, it failed with the same message.

I changed my `Architectures` to `armv7 i386` and now it seems to build fine at the command line for the simulator.

Despite the GUI indicating that Architectures of `Standard (armv7,armv7s)` includes just those two, I'm pretty sure there's an i386 hiding there when you build for the simulator.

In the end, that setting works fine now with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below command:
 xcodebuild -arch i386  -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 
But failed with similar error as clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=6.0'

Here is how I solved :

xcodebuild -arch i386 VALID_ARCHS="i386 armv7 armv7s" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO  -sdk iphonesimulator7.1

U need to make u set VALID_ARCHS and ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH correctly and it will work. You can make these settings on Xcode directly too.