# clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=5.0'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcodebuild

Now I am studying cocos2dx, and I use xcode build a demo, it's ok, but when I use xcodebuild to build it ,it's error.

```
xcodebuild -project proj.ios/CoinFlip.ios.xcodeproj -scheme CoinFlip.ios -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
```

and err information:

```
clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=5.0'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

How do I solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just solved a similar problem by following these steps:

1. adding `i386` into the `Valid Architectures` in the `TARGETS` section
2. adding `-arch i386` In the `xcodebuild` command arguments

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem, and @thomas's fix works for me. In case anyone needs a full script, see my answer here [xcodebuild test command for using with jenkins doesn´t work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051479/xcodebuild-test-command-for-using-with-jenkins-doesnt-work/18325089#18325089)